# tJava fetch string from print output in talend

Tags: java, printing, talend

currently I found an alternative to fetch the string output in Java using Talend Studio:

tJava code:

```
String output=((String)globalMap.get("tSystem_1_OUTPUT"));

System.out.println("Printing the error code 1 : "+StringUtils.substringBetween(output,"source count:", "destination count:"));
```

tJava output:

```
Printing the error code 1 : ', '1000')
('
```

[image]

Expected Result:

```
Printing the error code 1 : 1000
```

However, tJava takes the result exactly between string " source count:' " and " destination count: ", so that included the bracket and all. The expected result is only to get the value 1000.

How do I apply this java code to fetch the correct output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Haven't test this within Talend itself but try this ...

```
String output=((String)globalMap.get("tSystem_1_OUTPUT"));
var sourceCount = output.split("\\)")[0].split(",")[1].replace("'", "").trim();

System.out.println("Printing the error code 1 : " + sourceCount);
```

Comment: Thanks. that should work. will save it for future reference

Comment: Dude, if it worked, you should flag it answer the answer. Do you know how to do that? If not, turn the grey check mark/tick to green by clicking on it. It rewards those who help.